# cadastro de subcategoria e categoria

Tags: php

Boa tarde estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo cadastrar categoria e subcategoria na tabela de produto no meu banco de dados tem uma coluna que chama id_subcategoria e outra id_categoria e preciso que nessas tabelas apareça o id da subcategoria e categoria.Esse id vem de outra tabela que se chama categoria e subcategoria.

```html
<?php
require_once 'sessao.php';
require_once 'connection.php';

$stmt = $conexao->query('select * from categoria');
$categorias = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
?>

<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/busca_categoria.js"></script>
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
        
        
     <form action="produto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         Categoria:<br>
     <select name="categoria" id="categoria">
      <option value="">Selecione Uma Opcao</option>

       <?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria ): ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $categoria->id_categoria;?>"><?php echo $categoria->tx_nome;?></option>
             <?php endforeach ?>
      
     </select>

    <br><br>

 Subcategoria:<br>
     <select name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria">

     </select>
        <input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple />
         <input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload" />
     </form>
        
        
        
        
        
        <?php 
         if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
         {
             
             $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","otimi314_imagens","WkJJu336@otimi","otimi314_naoapagar");
             
             for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["file_img"]["name"]); $i++)
             {
                 $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                 $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
                 $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
                 $filepath = "imagens/fotos/" .$filename;
                 
                 
                 move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
                 $sql = "INSERT INTO produto (tx_imagem,img_path,img_type,id_subcategoria,id_categoria) VALUES ('$filename', '$filepath', '$filetype', 'id_subcategoria','id_categoria')";
                 
                  
                 mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                 

                 
  
             }
             
             
         }
   
        ?>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vinicius me parece que você não traz em seu código a seleção da subcategoria. Você executa um _foreach_ para **categorias**, mas precisaria com base nesta, selecionar a _subcategoria_ confere?

Comment: Olá Renato!!  Não, o que não estou conseguindo é cadastrar no banco de dados,  categoria e subcategoria.

Comment: Eu já tenho o código puxando o select da subcategoria